# PHP & MySQL code generation from UML

Tags: php, eclipse, uml

Is there an Eclipse plug-in that will allow me to graphically generate a data model, and produce from it a MySQL Database Script for generation of that database, and generate PHP code for simple add/change/delete methods?

This way I can focus on programming the business logic, instead of fussing with the details of the SQL code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use what is called a framework or ORM. Kohana is a good one, as is codeIgniter, and Doctrine. You can specify your data models in one location and have the DB and code generated. I'm not sure about generating it from a UML model tho.

Comment: Thanks.  Actually I found the RISE Editor at www.RiseToBloome.Com and that more than does the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [UMLtoPHP](http://modeling-languages.com/content/uml2php-full-code-generation-php-applications) online generation service that can take as input a UML Eclipse class diagram and generate the corresponding doctrine file for you. With that you can easily generate a full CRUD php application using, for instance, symfony